# Can a simple command line web browser be written in one line of Perl?

Tags: perl

Quite a while ago I ran across a reference that described writing a simple command line Perl script that acted as a web browser.  The shock factor to the demo script was that it was just one line of Perl.  I don't recall what the reference was.

How would someone do this?  Or, do you know of the reference I'm referring to?

Comment: *Very* simple that would be. And propably incredibly instable.

Answer (score 4):

You can try a modern web client of Perl:

```
perl -MMojo::Client -e "print Mojo::Client->new->get('http://www.example.com')->res->body;"
```

Inspired from:
http://www.slideshare.net/marcusramberg/mojo-as-aclient

Answer (score 3):

One line of Perl? *No.*

One line of Perl and a bunch of modules containing more lines of Perl? *Yes.*

One line of Perl and a bunch of such modules that you could download from the [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/)? Maybe.

A very basic HTML renderer might look like:

```
 perl -Mv5.10 -MLWP::Simple -MHTML::TreeBuilder::XPath -e"say HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new->parse(LWP::Simple::get('http://example.com'))->eof->as_text();"
```

Comment: It's just as possible as doing it in one line of C. It will probably be a very long line though

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it's reasonable to say that you could write a web browser in one line of Perl, although you could write a very simplistic HTTP client in one (long) line of Perl.

```
perl -MIO::Socket::INET -e 'die unless ($host, $path) = shift =~ m{http://(\w+(?:.\w+)*)(/.*)}; my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr=>$host,Proto=>"tcp",PeerPort=>80) or die; print $sock "GET $path HTTP/1.0\nHost: $host\n\n"; while (<$sock>) { print }' http://www.google.com/
```

Using `IO::Socket::INET` might be a bit of a cheat since it has more than one line in its source, but it has been core since forever and saves about 5 cookie cutter function calls to set up the socket.

Although in all honesty the one line I usually used for a simple Perl HTTP client is

```
GET http://www.google.com/
```